# New command with an Underscore

Tags: macros

I tried creating a new command with an underscore as shown below, but doesn't work.

```
\newcommand{\h\_world}[1]{Hello World #1}
```

At the output I see without even initiating the command :
**worldHello World 1**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't do it, unless there is a special reason to.

Underscores have special meaning (category code 8), to denote a subscript in math mode. Only catcode 11 (alphabetic) characters can be invoked in a macro name as `\macroname`.

Other approaches could be used to place an underscore in a macro name as shown below, but gyrations are required to invoke the macro name.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname h_world\endcsname[1]{Hello World #1}

\csname h_world\endcsname{!!!}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the space before the exclamation points is there because `!!!` is the argument to `\csname h_world\endcsname`, and shows up, after as space, as `#1` in the output of that macro.

See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/catcode for more explanation of available catcodes.

**ADDENDUM**

If you were crazy and had to implement, without the use of `\csname` a syntax of `\h_world`, here is a possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\h{\@ifnextchar_{\haux}{\loneh}}
\makeatother
\def\tmpcompare{world}
\def\haux_#1 {\def\tmp{#1}\ifx\tmp\tmpcompare Hello World \else\loneh_#1 \fi}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\loneh{[\string\h{} undefined]}

\h blah

$\h_something blah$

\h_world blah

\bigskip\renewcommand\loneh{H}

\h blah

$\h_something blah$

\h_world blah
\end{document}
```

[image]

The first group of 3 lines tests

1. `\h` by itself, whose action is now defined in `\loneh`
2. `\h_<incorrect keyword>` where `incorrect keyword` is anything other than the string `world`.  It produces the result `\loneh_<incorrect keyword>` where the underscore is taken with the traditional meaning.
3. `\h_world`, with the desired output.

In the first group of 3 lines `\loneh` is defined as `[\string\h{} undefined]` and in the second group of 3 lines, it is defined simply as `H`.

Comment: Makes life complicated o_O

Comment: @user42826 Please see my addendum.

Comment: why a macro name is so restricted to be only alphabetic? Not even number is allowed?

Comment: @liang That is the way Knuth designed the TeX language.  Of course, it can also be changed, by redefining other characters to be `\catcode` = 11, but that may cause other issues, if you call on pre-defined macros or blend your code with pre-existing code that has not also been defined with your catcode revision in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Using `\def` it may seem that you can use underscores in macros:

```
\def\nr_b{3}
\def\h_w#1{Hello #1 world!}
the number \nr_b is 3,
\h_w{wonderful}
```

will work exactly as requested by the OP, and produce

```
the number 3 is 3, Hello wonderful world!
```

(I tested it with `pdftex` , `xetex` , `luatex`, and also the respective `LaTeX` enginges ; all from TeX Live 2016).

I am no expert in TeX, but I think that, though, the above does not define a macro named `\nr_b` but rather a macro named `\nr` that can be only used when followed by `\_b`.

Moreover using underscores can have unpleasant side effects, as in this example

```
\def\int_{ARGH}
\[\int_\alpha\]
```

so I recommend against using underscores in macros.

Comment: Let me also add kudos to the authors of plastex: they reimplemented the TeX engine so well that it mimics also the weird behaviour above, and the errors you get when trying to use the macro \nr

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Nice answer! That's exactly what happens. Indeed if you try to define `\nr_somethingelse` the previous `\nr_b` will no longer exist, because the _actual_ macro is `\nr` in both cases. However if you change the category code of `_` (with ``\catcode`\_=11``) or use `\csname nr_b\endcsname` then `_` will be valid in macro names. For example in `expl3` we change the catcode of both `_` and `:` so that they can be used in macro names (the change happens inside `\ExplSyntaxOn/Off`). See this question for an example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/513196/134574

Comment: "using underscores can have unpleasant side effects, as in this example" - could you please comment on your example? I don't fully understand what you mean. Do you mean that you silently overwrote the standard macros \int and got problems because of that? But if you name your macros as int_argh, will it stop interfering with *int*?