# How to use \cs_generate_variant:Nn to compare token lists?

Tags: conditionals, expl3, token-lists

I want to deal with [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55600/comparing-latex3-token-list-to-string) by my method. The example below is some codes from [`interface3.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf); But throws the error:

> ! LaTeX3 Error: Variant form 'VV' deprecated for base form '\tl_if_eq:NNTF'.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { abc }
\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl { \tl_to_str:n { abc } }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_eq:NNTF { VV } % without this line, the result is falue, I want to get true with this line.
\tl_if_eq:VVTF \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpb_tl { true } { false }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: But the two token lists aren't equal. One is a _token list_ `abc`, and the other is _a string_ `abc`.

Comment: @Oleinik thanks. but why there is a bug with this code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two issues. The first is that a `V` argument doesn't really make sense as variant for an `N` argument (that's why it's deprecated). When you get the `V`alue of a variable, the result will not necessarily be a single token, so the `N` argument will fail. That's why you can only make `V` variants of `n` arguments.

The second is that one token list contains the *letter tokens* `abc` (`\tl_analysis_show:N \l_tmpa_tl` shows):

```
The token list \l_tmpa_tl contains the tokens:
>  a (the letter a)
>  b (the letter b)
>  c (the letter c)
```

while the second token list contains the *character tokens* `abc` (`\tl_analysis_show:N \l_tmpb_tl`):

```
The token list \l_tmpb_tl contains the tokens:
>  a (the character a)
>  b (the character b)
>  c (the character c)
```

so they are not equal when doing a *token list* comparison. You need a *string* comparison here:

```latex
\str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str { abc }
\str_set:Nx \l_tmpb_str { \tl_to_str:n { abc } }
\str_if_eq:VVTF \l_tmpa_str \l_tmpb_str { true } { false }
```

Note that `\str_set:Nx \l_tmpb_str { \tl_to_str:n { abc } }` is redundant. The argument of `\str_set:Nx` (and other `str` functions) is already passed through `\tl_to_str:n`.

Comment: shouldn't the first `n` be `N`?

Comment: thanks, I read interface3 more carefully after reading your nice answer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oops ;-)

Answer (score 8):

There is no reason to define variants (besides being wrong to begin with, in this case):

```latex
\tl_if_eq:NNTF \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpb_tl {true} {false}
```

is already the thing to do (and yields false in your case).

You might think to do a comparison between an explicit token list and (the contents of) a token list variable, defining variants of `\tl_if_eq:nnTF`.

You can do

```latex
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \tl_if_eq:nn {Vn,nV} { T,F,TF }
```

and now something like

```latex
\tl_if_eq:nVTF {abc} \l_tmpb_tl {true} {false}
\tl_if_eq:VnTF \l_tmpa_tl {abc} {true} {false}
```

will work (in your case the former yields false, the latter yields true).

The function `\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn` is a wrapper around `\cs_generate_variant:Nn` that's meant to define variants for conditional functions (signature ending in `TF`, `T` or `F`); it avoids having to apply several times the basic function.

With the code above you define all variants

```latex
\tl_if_eq:nVTF
\tl_if_eq:nVT
\tl_if_eq:nVF
\tl_if_eq:VnTF
\tl_if_eq:VnT
\tl_if_eq:VnF
```

at once. Note that defining `\tl_if_eq:VVTF` is useless, because it would be the same as `\tl_if_eq:NNTF`, just slower and not fully expandable.

Comment: thanks for your answer.

Comment: `\tl_if_eq:NNTF` would not be the same as `\tl_if_eq:VVTF`. The former is expandable, while the latter, being based on `\tl_if_eq:nnTF` would not be.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Right, I'll add it.